# Mecha anime where 2 girls fight with mechas

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

Looking for a mecha anime I saw on a YouTube ad; it's was about 15 mins long and started out showing a girl being choked by a girl with white hair and yellow eyes. The girl being choked had blue hair in a ponytail touches the girl choking her and her eyes turn blue, she throws the girl and she starts screaming and holding her head.

The girl with blue hair was wearing kinda scimpy red dress.

The girl with yellow eyes had this white dress on that came out in what looked like flower petals and on each "petal" there was like a black circle on it but anytime she needed to summon something yellow electricity would spark around her dress like that's where the power was coming from.

Once her eyes turn yellow again she starts laughing and summoning white robots through a power in her dress. And one of these robots goes to kill the girl that had been thrown but a blue black robot saves her. The girl is supposed and looked  behind her to see all these blue robots came to help her fight. So the white robots come from holes that are almost like rips in the dimension.

At one point the blue robots all throw everything they have at her and the yellow eyes girls laughs as she sees the blaze coming towards her and waves her hand and all the bullets that were coming for her go into these rips in space. Then she waves her hand again and they're all in a sphere in her hand and she  throws it back at the other girl.

The last part of it was the the last robot she summons is like a white dragon looking thing and than that was it it cut out.

Comment: Hi there! :) could you maybe take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, do you remember on which video that ad was displayed? Also, YouTube ads are often "targeted" by what you previously watched - did you watch several videos related to a same anime, for instance? If so, could you maybe indicate which one? (without posting your entire YouTube history, but that could provide some guidance! :) )

Comment: See but that's the thing I hadn't watched any anime in a long time. And I never watch mecha but this one just hooked me and it came up while I was watching like ghost vids haha but ya I'll check it out and edit. Sry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you saw was not an anime, but a trailer for a mobile game called *[Honkai Impact 3](http://www.global.honkaiimpact3.com/)*. [Here it is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rr-fpfCr3PE&t=18s). I am afraid I've never played the game myself so I can't tell you anything more about it.

(I won't bother listing all the parallels between the video and what you saw because your memory of the thing is pretty much spot on)